# Run service after logging in on an X session

Tags: ubuntu, services, lightdm

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to automatically start a service after login with LightDM. This service is not meant to start on boot, but after X is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to run after you login (which is how I read the title of your question), search for `Startup Application` in Unity and add your service there. If you are using the older desktop of Ubuntu Classic you should have something like that in the menu System Tools → Preferences → Startup Applications

Comment: You are right... It will depend on what he/she exactly wants to do. The question formulation needs to be enhanced.
( I like the way we meet in lots of question Anthon :)) )

Comment: Bichoy's solution does run in the user's session (so after login), not when the X server is initialized. But it doesn't run after a graphical login.